# Can I query the size of a database in influx db 2

Tags: influxdb-2

I looked through the influx nodes and I can't find an example of how to get the total size of a particular bucket. Is this possible, I'm using 2.x databases.

Comment: I am using OSS (docker hub Image URI: influxdb:2.0.7). I’ve created a bucket named ‘TelemetryData’ and have ingested data into it. I would like to know how much disk space this bucket has taken using flux query.
For now, I am using below shell command to get bucket size:
du -sh /var/influxdb/engine/data/Bucket ID/

Answer (score 1):

In InfluxDB v2.x, you could take advantage of the internal stats as following:

```
from(bucket: "yourBucket")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "storage_shard_disk_size")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "gauge")
    |> last()
```

It will show you the size of each database.
[image]

Comment: At `v.timeRangeStart` and `v.timeRangeStop` I'm getting:
`Error: failed to execute query: 400 Bad Request: error @1:49-1:50: undefined identifier v`
What does v mean in this Flux expression?

Comment: Can you double check the Variables tab on the Chronograf according to https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/visualize-data/variables/?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing springs immediately to mind in Flux to do this but you could just backup one specific bucket using the [influx backup](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/cli/influx/backup/) command and then just query the local directory size in your filesystem.

Comment: I am using OSS (docker hub Image URI: influxdb:2.0.7). I’ve created a bucket named ‘TelemetryData’ and have ingested data into it. I would like to know how much disk space this bucket has taken using flux query.
For now, I am using below shell command to get bucket size:
du -sh /var/influxdb/engine/data/Bucket ID/